# Converting date in text input string into other format javascript

Tags: javascript

The date input I have is for e.g.

```
var startDate = "January 16, 2013"
```

From older posts I tried to dig into, I know that I might need to use date.js from http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/documentation.php

So I had an extra line in my html to fire it up

```
<script src="http://prestigeswimming.com/wp-content/plugins/cred-frontend-editor/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   var startDate = "January 16, 2013"
   alert(startDate.getMonthName());
</script>
```

Am I supposed to do this to get an alert box saying "January"?

Comment: Side note: Date.js hasn't been maintained in years, and has a couple of parsing bugs around midnight. You might look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @EmersonF, if you are able to change your date format when inputting it, you should make sure you follow this specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no need to use a library:

```
var startDate = "January 16, 2013";
var d = new Date(startDate);
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

alert(month + "-" + day + "-" + year);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPBSf/

The following will convert your date format into a valid ECMAScript date format:

```
var startDate = "ApRiL 16, 2013";
var noCommas = startDate.replace(/\,/g,'');
var withDashes = noCommas.replace(/ /g,"-");

function monthsToNumbers(date)
{
  var months = ["january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"];
  var year;

  date = date.toLowerCase();

  for(var i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
  {
    if(date.indexOf(months[i]) != -1)
    {
      if(i+1 < 10)
        date = date.replace(months[i],"0" + (i+1));
      else
        date = date.replace(months[i],i+1);
    }
  }

  year = date.match(/\d{4}/);
  date = date.replace(year, "");
  date = year + "-" + date;
  date = date.substring(0,date.length-1);

  return date;
}

var d = new Date(monthsToNumbers(withDashes));
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

alert(d);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kWzSv/1/

Comment: You're relying on the `Date` constructor being able to parse that date, but the date is not in a format [documented by the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). So it may work for you, with your particular browser's JavaScript engine, in your particular locale, but it's not something you can rely on.

Comment: @ Alex: Again: **In your locale**. Did you test it with a French locale? Vietnamese? Using undocumented features, when you have a choice, is just not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I think `split(" ")[0]` would be better than hoping the parser works.

Comment: Added a new function to try and convert his format into an ECMAScript valid date format.

Answer (score 2):

Try this new version of the the line:

```
var startDate = Date.parseString( "January 16, 2013");
```

In order to use the library you have to make use of the Date() object.

parseString is a function on that object that returns a Date object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - That is not what this documentation page seemed to say, search for parseString there => http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/date/documentation.php.  I'll admit, I didn't test it.

Comment: @ Hogan: It must be a different DateJS library! (The name is generic enough, eh?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with US locale dates and need to parse arbitrary string inputs into dates, you could also check out [Sherlock.js](https://github.com/Tabule/Sherlock) for parsing the string into a Date object. Then, to get the month name, simply manipulate in Javascript:

```
var Sherlocked = Sherlock.parse('January 16');
var month = Sherlocked.startDate.getMonth();
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
alert(months[month]);
```

Sherlock.js won't parse the year though. If you need support for that, you could parse the year out yourself using Sherlock's preprocessor system.

*Disclosure:* I am the creator of Sherlock.js